# How to calculate last 4 any weekdays sales in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to calculate last 4 any weekdays total sales.Based on filter max date.
Example: I have 2 filter 
1. Date range(From -To)
2. Week Day(Like Mon,Tue Etc.)

I need total sales for last 4 Monday or Tuesday (as per above filter ).And Last 4 weekdays will be calculated based on To-date in filter.
Like To-date is 31-Dec'18 then last 4 Tuesday will be 4,11,18,25 Dec.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Nitika, the best way to do that is creating another table to put a 'Dimension' with dates, int that you can put, weekday, day, holiday, year, month...

Something like that:

[Do You Need a Date Dimension?](http://radacad.com/do-you-need-a-date-dimension)

[Why use a Date Dimension Table in a Data Warehouse](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/blog/b/community_blog/posts/why-use-a-date-dimension-table-in-a-data-warehouse)

Doing that you can reference your atual date with this table, and get just the weekday that you are looking for